# Tracking multiple URLs as a single page with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url, tracking

I run a website where the user is able to create a bespoke page from a template, which is published with a custom URL. For example:

```
 http://example.com/customer-bespoke-url-1
 http://example.com/customer-bespoke-url-2
 http://example.com/customer-bespoke-url-3
```

Each of these URLs serve a templated page with custom content, depending upon the URL, but the overall design and layout is the same.

I would like to have the option to track traffic on these pages as a single entity within Google Analytics, that is combine all the data for these pages together when I need to view the overall effectiveness of the page.

Is there a way I can mark these pages to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using [Content Grouping](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en).

You create Content Groupings at the view level by going to: *Admin -> View> -> Content Grouping*.

As covered [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en):

> You have three options for how you assign content:
>
> - Group by Tracking Code (modify the tracking code on each web page):
>
> Add a single line of code that identifies the content index number and
>   the Content Group to which that content belongs.
>
> - Group Using Extraction (extract content based on URL or page title)
>
> Use a regular expression to identify a full or partial URL, page
>   title, or screen name.
>
> - Group Using Rule Definitions:
>
> Use the rules editor to create simple rules to identify content.